# List of valuable hotkeys and shortcuts

Tags: civilization-4, civilization-4-beyond-the-sword

I am looking for a complete list of special hotkeys and shortcuts in a orderly manner to make living as a god easier. I am not looking for the obvious like "i" to irrigate or "r" for road but it might be good to provide these unit orders in a separate section. I already discovered an extensive amount of hotkeys like adding city orders in front or back of the building cue, having units be produced infinity, setting a rally point cities, etc. I will grant a day or two for someone to provide an extensive list and I or anyone can add to that, just make sure you did some homework before you post an answer.

Comment: Heh, good job on [asking nicely](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/159093/1). 
[**Here**](http://www.civfanatics.com/civ4/reference/shortcuts.php)'s a fairly extensive list. Now [go do your own homework](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/159093/1).

Comment: @oKtosiTe I am just giving someone the time to put down an answer. Believe me there are some awesome shortcuts that not many people know about. Just not sure why i get the downvotes. I am sure a list of these shortcuts will benefit all civ 4 players.

Comment: @oKtosiTe You might as well make that an answer.

Comment: @DJClayworth: I might as well. :-)

Comment: Why the downvotes? Maybe because you ask for a list which could be obtained with a quick Google search? Or maybe because you are "granting a day or two" to people to post answers on a website where contributions are made freely, in the spirit of helping other people, rather than on a "I grant you a day or two to comply to my demands" basis? Or maybe because you are warning people to do their homework while you obviously didn't do yours?

Answer (score 1):

A fairly extensive list can be found [here](http://www.civfanatics.com/civ4/reference/shortcuts.php).